# Does extending a ruby class violate the LSP?

Tags: ruby, solid

I am reading about SOLID principles. In Ruby tutorials and code samples, I often see subclass extensions like:

```
class House
  attr_reader :items
end

class Room < House
  attr_reader :chair
end

p House.chair = 'baroque_style'# => NoMethodError
```

Of course the examples are useful to show how easily classes are manipulate in ruby, but isn't this a violation of the Liskov Substitution Principle?

Comment: Saying that a woman is less than a person is not funny.

Comment: Sorry, that came out badly, there was no intention of insulting women or anyone else for the matter. I changed the code sample, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Sorry, I was intended to be taken as a second degree joke. Next time I'll be less subtle ಠ_ಠ. I hope I did not scare you. ​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: I didn't get the sarcasm, but I prefer this example anyway. At this age and time IMHO is wiser to avoid this kind of misunderstandings.

Comment: Side note, usually this should be true: DerivedClass *is a* BaseClass.  In your example Room *is a* House is not true, which should raise a red flag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, LSP states that if S is a subtype of T, you should be able to use an S whenever a T is expected.

In your example, `Room` is a subtype of `House`, so we should be able to pass an instance of `Room` to anything expecting a `House`. What you then do is to pass a `House` into code expecting a `Room` (so you are using a T, where an S is expected).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. So - to make sure I understood the principle - a violation will happen if we choose to override a method defined in *T* by re-defining it on class *S*? (e.g. if `T.method1.is_a? String` and `S.method1.is_a? FixNum`)

Comment: Your comment is very misleading. It's not about the methods that `T` and `S` respond to, it's about the methods that *instances* of `S` and `T` respond to. The *important* thing about the LSP is the *history rule*. The fact that the subtyping relationship between function types is contravariant in the subtyping relationship of the argument types and covariant in the subtyping relationship of the return types was well-known long before that (and is kind-of obvious anyway). The novel contribution of the LSP is a) the formulation in terms of substitutability and b) the history rule, which makes …

Comment: … it applicable to mutable types with identity, whereas the earlier formulation in terms of variance of function types only ever considered pure functions.

Comment: @JörgWMittag sorry but I do not understand the basic concept here. I need to study and see some real world examples. My point is that I cant follow your reasoning, unfortunately. Thanks, at least you showed me that I totally missed the point, I must go to square one.

Comment: I suspect `Cat` and `Mammal` are better examples than `Room` and `House`. Sub-classes should, in general, follow an "is-a" relation (so, neither a "has-a" or "exists-in").